# check/uncheckbox in gridview tracking

Tags: asp.net, gridview

i have a below gridview control with a checkbox on it,  so my question is when i hit on save button i able to find the checkbox which have been checked and till here no problem, but the problem started when the user tries to uncheck the checkedbox so how would i track the changes and save it into the db that has been checked. anyhelp?

```
List<Employee> result = new List<Employee>();
    long Id = (long)Session["Id"];
    result = Employee.GetEmployeeById(Id);

foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
{
   CheckBox chkBox = row.FindControl("chkSelected") as CheckBox;
   if (c != null)
   {
      if (result.Count > 0)
      {
          foreach (Employee item in result)
          {
             Label Id = row.FindControl("lblId") as Label;
             if (Id.Text == item.Id.ToString())
             {
                 chkBox.Checked = true;
             }
             else
             {
                chkBox.Checked = false;
             }
           }
       }

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelected" runat="server" Checked="false"></asp:CheckBox>
  </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function SelectAll(cb)
    {
        var gvVar = document.getElementById("<%= gv.ClientID %>");
        var cell;
        if (gvVar.rows.length > 0)
        {
            for (i=1; i<gvVar.rows.length; i++)
            {
                cell = gvVar.rows[i].cells[0];
                for (j=0; j<cell.childNodes.length; j++)
                {                          
                    if (cell.childNodes[j].type =="checkbox")
                    {
                        cell.childNodes[j].checked = document.getElementById(cb).checked;

                    }
                }

            }
        } 
    }
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.
   function Select(cb)
    {
        var total = parseInt('<%= this.gv.Rows.Count %>');
        var counter=0;
        var cbSelectAll=document.getElementById(cb);
        var gvVar = document.getElementById("<%= gv.ClientID %>");
        var cell;
        if (gvVar.rows.length > 0)
        {
            for (i=1; i<gvVar.rows.length; i++)
            {
                cell = gvVar.rows[i].cells[0];
                for (j=0; j<cell.childNodes.length; j++)
                {                          
                    if (cell.childNodes[j].type =="checkbox")
                    {
                        if(cell.childNodes[j].checked)
                        counter++;
                        else
                        counter--;

                    }
                }

            }
        }
        if(counter==total)
        cbSelectAll.checked=true;
        else if(counter<total)
        cbSelectAll.checked=false;
    }
</script>

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Normal || e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Alternate))
        {
            CheckBox cbSelect = (CheckBox)e.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("cbSelect");
            CheckBox cbSelectAll = (CheckBox)this.gv.HeaderRow.FindControl("cbSelectAll");
            cbSelect.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:Select('" + cbSelectAll.ClientID + "')"); 
            cbSelectAll.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:SelectAll('" + cbSelectAll.ClientID + "')");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, store the original value in a hidden field.  If always starting with false, you could use JavaScript to set the hidden value to true when the user clicked the checkbox.  Using JQuery, you could do:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" ItemStyle-CssClass="Checked">
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelected" runat="server" Checked="false"></asp:CheckBox>
  <asp:HiddenField iD="dh" runat="server" />
  </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>

$("#<%= Grid.ClientID %>").find(".Checked > :checkbox").each(function() {
   $(this).siblings("input[type='hidden']").attr("value", "True");
});
```

Something like that.  On Server side, parse the value and if true, then you know it changed.

HTH.

Comment: hmm....is there only the option? i am leaning towards storing in object and compare? any thoughts

Comment: here is the catch, the ones i checked i will be storing in the db with active=true and the one that is unchecked i will be storing in the db with active=false... so in both ways i will be storing... your solution will work with this scanrio ?

Comment: You could also store in the hidden field the original value, so you would bind the original active state to the hidden and the checkbox at the same time, and then compare the two values to determine if they changed.  But from what it looked like in your original post, initially it was always false, so I couldn't tell what you were looking for.  From what you said, you wanted to know when someone checked a record, and the solution with the hidden field will capture that they did check it by setting the value to true.  Either of these ways, the hidden will work.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the brightest idea, but you can query the database for the current state, and the compare with what you have got from the web page during a postback button click, or something like that. Or you can go with Brians answer.

It is possible to persist a list of objects into the Viewstate and access it in a consequent postback. The only thing is that the object you are trying to persist must be defined as serializable.

Update:

The ViewState approach

I feel this may be suitable for your need, and it requires a bit of linq. You'd need to create a class as follows:

```
[Serializable()]
public class OptionState
{
    //the id of the item
    int ID {get;set;}
    //state of the checkbox
    bool Checked {get;set;}
}
```

Note the Serializable attribute. This is required for the instance to persist to the viewstate.

Add the list of options to the viewstate:

```
var lstOptions = (from x in <your_option_store> 
    select new OptionState{ID = x.ID, Checked = x.Checked}).ToList();
ViewState.Add("options", lstOptions);
```

Here is a bit of code that should go into your button click:

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in gvOptions.Rows)
{

    //not writing the bit of code
    //which gets the ID and the 
    //state of checkbox of 
    //the gridview row being processed
    OptionState currentState = GetOptionStateObjectFromRow(row);
    List<OptionState> lstStates = (List<OptionState>) ViewState["options"];
    OptionState originalState = lstStates.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == currentState.ID);
    if(currentState.Checked != originalState.Checked)
    {

        //the appropriate db call needs to be done here.

    }

}
```

Comment: i am query the db and to get the fresh copy of what the user have already selected and then what the user have add/change but the comaping is not quite working.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Be warned the code was written out of haste. Come back if you have any doubts or errors in the code.